# How do I pass this list view array in to next activity?

Tags: listview, android-intent

```
public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int serviceCode) {
    Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
    switch (serviceCode) {
        case jsoncode:

            if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
                playersModelArrayList = parseContent.getInfo(response);
                customeAdapter = new CustomeAdapter(this,playersModelArrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(customeAdapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewKid.this,ViewMap.class);

                        intent.putExtras();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ViewKid.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```

}

I want to pass my list view data to another activity, can anyone help? what shall I put in the intent.putExtras();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you want to do.. if you want to pass the whole array list data just use:

```
Intent.putArrayListExtra(playersModelArrayList);
```

If you want to pass the item that user select:

```
Intent.putExtra(playersModelArrayList.get(position));
```

Comment: 'holder.tvname.setText("Name: "+playersModelArrayList.get(position).getKName());
holder.tvlatitude.setText("Latitude: "+playersModelArrayList.get(position).getLatitude());
        holder.tvlongitude.setText("Longitude: "+playersModelArrayList.get(position).getLongitude());'                                
I want to pass latitude and longitude data to new activity.

Comment: 'Intent.putExtra(playersModelArrayList.get(position));'


having error

Comment: Ok! So if I anderstund you want to pass not all the data but only the lattitude and longitude which are two strings I guess! So...
intent.putStringExtras("lattitude",lattitude);
Intent.putStringExtras("longitude",longitude);

Comment: In general if you want to pass objects throught activity it depends by the object you are working with! The most important objects have theire own methods like putStringExtra() for string... if you want to pass a custom object that you created, this object must implement the parcelable interface to be pass throught activities... but if you need to pass only strings this is not youre case